# Emails not getting delivered to users in China

Tags: linux, email, php, postfix, dkim

I’m facing a strange issue with a codeigniter application which sends emails to registered users. The issues is that most Chinese users are not receiving emails which were sent from the application.

As far as I know, SPF records on DNS are configured, we are using Postfix to trigger emails and also have DKIM signature.

Somebody please advise? What is the right configuration for this?

Comment: Could you post your email/smtp server log files?

Comment: We are using Ubuntu server. Could you please clarify that you are asking for /var/log/mail.log file or any thing else?

Comment: It should be good to start narrowing possibilities.